# How can I display "Tomorrow" of calendar list in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails.

I tried to create a calendar list and I encountered some problem.

I have done it like this:

[image]

There are my code

View:

```
<% @start_date.each do |day, posts| %>
 <% if day.today? %>
  <h4 id="today_title">Today <%= day.strftime("%b %d")%></h4>
  <% posts.each do |post| %>
    <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %></p>
  <%end%>   
 <%else%>
  <h4 class="other_day_title"><%= day.strftime("%A %b %d") %></h4>
  <% posts.each do |post| %>
    <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %></p>
  <%end%>
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Controller:

```
def index
 @posts = Post.all.order(:start_time)
 @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
 @start_date = @posts.group_by {|t| t.start_time.beginning_of_day }
end
```

Similarly,I try the some code as `<% if day.today? %>` to display the tomorrow bar like this:

```
<% if (day+1).today? %>

<% if day.today+1.day? %>

<% if day.today.next_day? %>

<% if day.tomorrow? %>
```

But I got the some error :

```
undefined method `today' for Sun, 07 Feb 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00:Time
```

There is any answer about it?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: try `(day+1).to_date.today?`

Comment: @UriAgassi It show the date of today(Feb 09)

Comment: @ChamperWu in your code, `day` is actually an instance of `Time`. Therefore `+ 1` only adds one second as opposed to one day.

Comment: @stefan So I need to add `-86400` or `-1.day`, right?

Comment: I'd make `day` a `Date` instance by using `group_by { |t| t.start_time.to_date }`. This allows you to write `if day == Date.tomorrow` which IMO is easier to comprehend than `if day - 1.day == Date.today`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like:

```
<% if (day-1.day).to_date.today? %>
<% if day.to_date.eql?(Date.today+1.day) %>
<% if day.to_date.eql?(Date.today.next_day) %>
<% if day.to_date.eql?(Date.tomorrow) %>
```