# How can I group by date from star time to end time range in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails

As I have done : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292481/how-can-i-display-tomorrow-of-calendar-list-in-ruby-on-rails/35292751#35292751)

But, I add the end time data in SQLite, and I want to let the calendar list display like this :

Saturday Feb 07

- Traveling (start time)
- Buy something

Sunday Feb 08

- Traveling
- take care mom (start time)

Monday Feb 09

- Traveling (end time)
- take care mom

Tuesday Feb 10

- take care mom (end time)

So,I use `For loop` to do that

View:

```
    <% @start_date.each do |day, posts| %>
  <% if day.to_date == Date.today %>
    <h4 id="today_title">Today <%= day.strftime("%b %d")%></h4>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
      <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %> <%= post.start_time.strftime("%H:%M")%></p>
    <%end%>
  <%elsif day.to_date == Date.today-1.day %>
    <h4 class="other_day_title">Yesterday <%= day.strftime("%b %d")%></h4>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
      <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %> <%= post.start_time.strftime("%H:%M")%></p>
    <%end%>  
  <%elsif day.to_date == Date.today+1.day %>
    <h4 class="other_day_title">Tomorrow <%= day.strftime("%b %d")%></h4>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
      <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %> <%= post.start_time.strftime("%H:%M")%></p>
    <%end%>
  <%else%>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
    <% for daytime in post.start_time.to_date..post.end_time.to_date %>
      <h4 class="other_day_title"><%= daytime.strftime("%A %b %d") %></h4>
        <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %> <%= post.start_time.strftime("%H:%M")%> to <%= post.end_time.strftime("%A %b %d %H:%M")%></p>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Controller:

```
def index
@posts = Post.all.order(:start_time)
@date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
@start_date = @posts.group_by {|t| t.start_time.to_date}
@end_date = @posts.group_by {|t| t.end_time.to_date} 
end
```

and I got this:

[image]

It cant distribute the event to each day bar.

I try to change the controller

```
def index
@posts = Post.all.order(:start_time)
@date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
@start_date = @posts.group_by {|t| t.start_time.to_date..t.end_time.to_date}
@end_date = @posts.group_by {|t| t.end_time.to_date} 
end
```

and I got an error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for Tue, 09 Feb 2016..Wed, 10 Feb 2016:Range
```

How can I solve it?

thanks for reading :)

Comment: *"star time"* - I was hoping for a sci-fi question :-)

Comment: @Stefan, I was thinking that the class `Time` only applies to earth times.

Comment: @Stefan , thx for editing :)

Comment: Is it possible to use `map method` to display each day bar?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) the date and list all activities for each date. It would look something like this:

```
<% posts.group_by(&:date).each do |day, posts| %>
  <h4 class="other_day_title"><%= day.strftime("%A %b %d") %></h4>
  <% posts.each do |post| %>
    <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %> <%= post.start_time.strftime("%H:%M")%> to <%= post.end_time.strftime("%A %b %d %H:%M")%></p>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

I'm not sure exactly what your date field is called though.

Comment: Actually,yes! But,I want to `group_by` the range from start_time to end_time,not just start_time or end_time. It's different is 'days' and day