# How can I remove the same values from an array?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a calendar list in Ruby on Rails

I created a date range:

```
date_range = [['Feb 10', 'Feb 11'], ['Feb 11', 'Feb 12'], ['Feb 10', 'Feb 11', 'Feb 12']]
```

I ran this code:

```
date_range.each do |day|
  for daytime in day
    puts daytime
  end
end
```

The output is:

```
Feb 10 Feb 11 Feb 11 Feb 12 Feb 10 Feb 11 Feb 12
```

How can I display just:

```
Feb 10 Feb 11 Feb 12
```

Comment: Your `date_range` is not a valid object.

Comment: Apart from the syntax, your `date_range` seems to be an array of date pairs (i.e. a 2D array), whereas your output shows single dates. Could you explain that?

Comment: What are date bar and day bar?

Comment: Sorry,just date bar,and which I have done in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382295/how-can-i-group-by-date-from-star-time-to-end-time-range-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment58470095_35382295)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specifically get the result you're after, how about

```
date_range.flatten.uniq.zip
```

Comment: I don't know if `sort` was necessary.

Comment: @sawa Yeah, in his example it wasn't. I just wanted to give something a bit more robust.

Comment: @sawa I don't know too much about Rails and its use cases. Would you recommend removing the `sort`?

Comment: It depends on his intention (it may already be sorted). But since it is not asked, I think it is safer not to add your interpretation.

Comment: This code can let `date_range = ["Feb 10","Feb 11","Feb 12"]`,but it can't use `for loop` to print every date bar. I got an error `undefined method each for #<Post:0x007fe7ef0b0d18>`

Comment: @ChamperWu Hope I understood you correctly. See edit (`.zip`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way to do this (with straight face):

```
date_range.reduce(:|)
#=> ["Feb 10", "Feb 11", "Feb 12"]
```